# How to name a process for command and kill it later by name?

Tags: linux, bash, process

I need to make a short aux bash script to clear the logcat buffer and output afterwards in a file (new process).

The problem is that at every run I need to kill the previous process which dumps in the file (but I cannot kill the entire adb process).

```
adb -s $1 logcat -c
adb -s $1 logcat -v time > $1.log &
```

$1 - the device id

I would like that the second command `adb -s $1 logcat -v time > $1.log &` to run in a process named `$1` so I could kill it before running the other comands. Something like this:

```
pkill $1
adb -s $1 logcat -c
adb -s $1 logcat -v time > $1.log &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pkill takes a regex pattern. Use the `-f` option to search the whole command line.

```
pkill -f "adb .* $1 .* -v time"
```